# Regex for two numbers and space between

Tags: regex

I need to validate a property which can contain a two numbers(can be both float and integer) and they are separated with a space

So this should be valid:   72 72,278
This should be also valid: 72 72
this shouldn't be valid:   45   45 - more than one space between
this shouldn't be valid :  2,2     - just one float number
this shouldn't be valid:   23 # 12  - if it contain any other characters

I've tried like this:

```
  \d+[ ,]\d+
```

but this does not validate correctly if I have two float numbers, only if I have two integers and the space

I've also tried this

```
[0-9 .,]+
```

This validates what I need, but also validates invalid items

Comment: `^\d+(?:,\d+)? \d+(?:,\d+)?$`? See https://regex101.com/r/aNKv86/1

Comment: Do I understand correctly? You want to use commas as the decimal separator, and a space to split the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like so: `^\d+(,\d+)?(\s\d+(,\d+)?)+$`, example [here](https://regex101.com/r/ijOitw/1).

This assumes that:

- The `,` is your floating point delimeter;
- Negative numbers *aren't* allowed.

*EDIT*

As per Wiktor's comment, this solution accepts two **or more** numbers separated by a white space. To only accept 2 numbers, the following needs to be used: `^\d+(,\d+)?(\s\d+(,\d+)?)$`. (Notice the `+` at the end has been removed, changing the logic to 1 or more to just 1).

*EDIT 2*
As per your comment, if you need to match both the `,` and the `.` as separator, you would need to use something such as this: `^\d+([,.]\d+)?(\s\d+([,.]\d+)?)+$`. This will accept both characters as decimal separators, however, please note that as is, can accept something of the sort: `12.34 34,56`.

Comment: `^\d+(,\d+)?(\s\d+(,\d+)?)+$` [allows more than two numbers](https://regex101.com/r/ijOitw/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You are right, my understanding was it was two or more. I will fix the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and npinti - this works perfectly.Thanks! What if I need also the '.' to be accepted as a valid separator, not just the ',' So also the 12.12 23.23 to be accepted and also 12,12 12,23. I tried this ^\d+(,.\d+)?(\s\d+(,.\d+)?)+$ - but this is not ok.

Comment: @Orsi: I have updated my answer. Please note that `,.` to the engine means a period followed by a comma.